# How to allow CORS on Sharepoint 2013 Server

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have web application from where i am executing REST calls to Sharepoint Server 2013 to do some of the operation like create sites/subsites . Things were fine when executed from REST Web CLient .

But when executing from my web application , i am currently getting "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx:yyy/_api/contextinfo/?username=vvv&password=zzzz No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:yyyy' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Is it possible to enable CORS on Sharepoint server 2013 stating allow requests to come from a specific IP ?

Comment: Can you deploy farm solutions or make manage IIS settings?